# How to parsing data

Tags: php, laravel

my response to request in my laravel  aplication is:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [order_product_id] => 39           
        [ean] => 1255AA
        [quantity] => 1       
    )

[1] => Array
    (   
        [order_product_id] => 40  
        [ean] => 1326489131511
        [quantity] => 1

    )

   )
```

How to parsing this data in my aplication? 
I tried to:

```
 foreach ($request->all() as $data)
 {
 print_r($data['ean']);
 die(); 
 }
```

I get this error:  Undefined index: ean

Edit: When I  use var_export($request->all()) I get:

```
 array (
  'Array
(
____' => 
  array (
    0 => '> Array
        (
            [order_product_id] => 39
            [ean] => 1255AA
            [quantity] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [order_product_id] => 40
            [ean] => 1326489131511
            [quantity] => 1
        )    
)',
  ),
)
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset" using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undefined)

Comment: Are you getting all that data in your request object?

Comment: What do you get when you `var_export($request->all());`?

Comment: @Milan Can you edit and add this in your question with proper indendation?

Comment: Yes I update to my question.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like `$request->all()` returns data as something like that:

```
$array = [
    'Array ( ____' => [
        [
            'order_product_id' => 39,
            'order_id' => 34,
            'product_id' => 48,
            'name' => 'iPod Classic',
            'model' => 'product 20',
            'ean' => '1255AA',
            'quantity' => '1',
            'price' => 10.0000,
            'total' => 10.0000,
            'tax' => 0.0000,
            'reward' => 0    
        ],
   ]    
];
```

So, instaed of:

```
foreach ($request->all() as $data)
```

use:

```
foreach (array_shift($request->all()) as $data)
```

Comment: Thank you, but I get error: ErrorException: Only variables should be passed by reference in file .... on array_shift($request->all()) .

Comment: If you have result of command `var_export($request->all())`, there is something wrong.
It looks line:

['Array
(
____'] => 0 => string

Where string is:

`'> Array
        (
            [order_product_id] => 39
            [ean] => 1255AA
            [quantity] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [order_product_id] => 40
            [ean] => 1326489131511
            [quantity] => 1
        )    
)'`

Could you paste result of var_export($_POST) yet ?